# Sinatra + Ruby: Random Number keeps changing every time I guess. Scope issue?

Tags: ruby, random, sinatra

I am using Sinatra to build a WebGuesser with [Jumpstart Labs](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/web_guesser.html#i4%3a-extensions). I enter a number into a text field in my browser. I click submit and I am supposed to get a response saying if my number is too low or too high (or within 5). I use Shotgun to load the server. I want to be able to guess a number without having the random number change every time I guess.

**Code**:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'


def check_guess(guess)
if params["guess"].to_i == guess
        "You got it right!"
elsif params["guess"].to_i > guess 
    if params["guess"].to_i > (guess + 5)
        "Way too high!"
    else 
        "Close.. but too high!"
    end
elsif params["guess"].to_i < guess
    if params["guess"].to_i < (guess - 5)
        "Way too low!"
    else
        "Close.. but too low!"
    end
end
end 


# Home route
get '/' do 
    SECRET_NUMBER = rand(100)
    message = check_guess(SECRET_NUMBER)
    erb :index, :locals => { :message => message }
end
```

Currently, I get a new random number *every time* I guess which doesn't help. I feel like it may have something to do with where my SECRET_NUMBER is scope-wise. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Every time there is a GET request to `"/"`, the relevant code is executed, which generates (with warnings) a new `SECRET_NUMBER`.

One way to deal with this is to route to different URLs for the first guess (in which case a secret number should be generated), and the consecutive guesses (in which case a new secret number should not be generated).

Also, it is very bad practice to use a constant for something that changes over time.

Comment: `SECRET_NUMBER` is something [Jumpstart Lab](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/web_guesser.html#i4:-extensions) suggested. I do not understand why the author used a constant but i'm sure there must have been good reason.

Comment: Do you mean making a route like `GET '/blah blah' do ...SECRET_NUMBER... end` Thanks for reaching out btw.

Comment: Perhaps something like `GET '/new-question` and `GET '/guess'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the initial value in the user session, for that you would have to enable sessions in sinatra.

```
configure do
  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, "somesecretstring" 
end
```

After that you can create a number by going to a certain route

```
get '/random' do
  session[:number] = rand(100)
end
```

You can then check your guesses on a different route

```
get '/checkguess' do
  check_guess(session[:number]) unless session[:number].nil?
end
```

That's the basic thought, you'd have to define it further though. Hope it helps you a little

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the exact same question now and :

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/reloader"

number = rand(100)

get '/' do
  guess = params["guess"].to_i
  message = check_guess(guess, number)
  erb :index, :locals => {:bok => number, :alert => guess, :msg => message}
end
```

putting the rng outside the get block just worked. Generated number stays same until you change something in the code (even adding a space to the end and saving the file would work to re-random the number.) or restart the server completely.

About the constant(SECRET_NUMBER), it helps to give check_guess method only one argument since you define it as a constant at top. (since i'm new to ruby someone can correct me if i'm wrong.)

```
SECRET_NUMBER = rand(100)

get '/' do ... end

def check_guess(guess)
  if guess < SECRET_NUMBER
    "Your Guess is Too LOW!"
  elsif guess > SECRET_NUMBER
    "Your Guess is Too HIGH!"
  else
    "Conguratulations! You guessed it right:)"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for the answer. rand should be defined outside of get block

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
rand = (rand() * 100).to_i
get '/' do

  "The secret number is #{rand}"
end
```